Does iterating over promises actually runs them?
While working with googleapis library with a coworker, I've stumbled onto this error:
Uncaught GaxiosError Error: request to <gmail api url> failed, reason: connect EMFILE <xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxx> - Local (undefined:undefined)
    at _request (/gmail-api/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:149:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (<node_internals>/internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
gaxios.js:149
Process exited with code 1

It happened only if I tried to generate a list of promises to be used with Promise.all:
const promises = emailList.map((email) => {
      return this.gmailApi.users.messages.get({
        userId: 'me',
        id: email.id,
      })
    })

const resolvedPromises = await Promise.all(promises)

However, if instead I manually executed only the first 10 promises, without mapping each one to my promises variable, it would work. It seems it only causes the error AFTER I iterate each promise with the .map... My question is: Why does this happen? What is node doing behind the curtains?

Please [edit] this question to clearly distinguish it from this q/a, since you're running into the problem of opening too many file descriptors at once. Where in this code are you "iterating over promises"? It looks like you're iterating over emailList; is each entry of emailList a promise? If not, then you're not iterating over promises, you're iterating over something else, and each iteration is causing a get request and too many of those is the issue. If you do ten of them you have... fewer of those.

Promise.all requires all promises to succeed. If one fails, all remaining fail. Maybe try Promise.allSettled() to know which promise failed..

What does "if instead I manually executed only the first 10 promises" mean? Please show the code you're running.

@TheMaster "[then] all remaining fail" - rather, all the remaining (not yet fulfilled) promises are simply ignored. Promise.all forwards the first error, if there is any.

Each async operation begins executing immediately (when you call get({ ... })). It seems there's an issue with at least one entry in emailList that causes that async execution to fail

@Phil The the issue could also be starting too many requests at once

@Bergi seems something Google should be able to handle or at least I'd expect a 429 response. Client-side, Node.js shouldn't have a problem scheduling any number of requests

@Phil We don't know the size of emailList until the OP tells us, but it may very well be the problem. Operating systems may have rather low limits of connections per process. This code may work just fine with a different list or on a different machine.

@Bergi I thought Node.js was able to queue any number of requests. Even if it hits the maximum concurrency number it should still be able to handle the rest as the pool empties, just like browsers do

@Phil I don't think node.js keeps a pool by itself, like browsers do; the programmer has to implement that if they want it. There is no "maximum concurrency number". If the code hits an OS resource limit, it gets an error from the OS.

Do we agree that "does iterating over promises actually run them" is a red herring and not directly related the the underlying error in any meaningful way? The problem has nothing to do with "iterating over promises", does it? It's not even the fact that these are promises that's the problem. It's presumably that the OS can't handle the number of concurrent requests happening. Certainly the code is related to their problem, but the phrasing of the title and the question within seems to be misdirected. (And Promise.all is also not the issue here, at least not directly)

My apologies @Bergi, I missed the EMFILE part of the error. Probably duplicate - Node.js EMFILE error with increasing traffic

Side note: promises don't run or execute. They are objects not functions. Iterating over objects is just that: it doesn't do anything to those objects.

Try below code. i have made slight change in your code and handle some error.
i wanted to know .get() is a method which call other api if yes? then you can use axios package to get data by passing all authication token etc.


const fetchUserData = async (emailId) => {
    try{
        let data = await this.gmailApi.users.messages.get({
        userId: 'me',
        id: emailId,
      })
      return data
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
         return {}
    }
};

const userPromises = emailList.map(fetchUserData);

Promise.allSettled(userPromises)
  .then((users) => {
    console.log(users); 
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });




You don't need Promise.allSettled if you're ignoring errors via try/catch already
